# Why is my Stored Function giving me a "Not Valid in the Context" SQLSTATE=42887?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, stored-functions

[image]I made a Custom Stored function that returns all the Zip Codes for a terminal(variable iTerminal) in a specified radius(using the variable iBucket 1-5). I want it to return a 1 column Table/list but it keeps giving me SQLSTATE=42887. The SQL query runs fine as a stand alone piece but apparently I am doing something wrong in the Stored Function.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION magnum_service_bucket(iTerminal VARCHAR(10),iBucket_zone INTEGER)
  RETURNS TABLE(zone_id VARCHAR(10))

  LANGUAGE SQL
  SPECIFIC fn_magnum_service_bucket
  READS SQL DATA
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN ATOMIC
  RETURN
  select zone_id
  from( 
     Select 
        zone_id, 
        distance, 
        case when distance between 0 and 20 then 1 
           when distance between 21 and 50 then 2 
           when distance between 51 and 100 then 3 
           when distance between 101 and 150 then 4 
           else 5 
        end as bucket  
     From(
        select 
           zone_id,
           city,
           province,
           terminal_zone, 
           DIST_BETWEEN_ZONES((select postal_code from zone where zone_id = iTerminal ),zone_id) as distance 
        from zone 
        where service_type = 'DIRECT' 
        and zone_id in (select zone_id from terminal_multi where terminal_zone = iTerminal)
     )
  ) where bucket = iBucket_zone;
  END
```

Comment: Please include the _entire_ error message.

Comment: I added the picture to the top.

Comment: Bzzzt...wrong. The error message is about the function `MAGNUM_SERVICE_BUCKET`, which is nowhere to be found in the code you posted. Try again.

Comment: It is the Same Function I was just trying different itterations of it on a test server so I keep re-naming it so I can track whats changed in case i stumbled upon the "Fix"

Comment: Well, the problem obviously is not in the function, but in wherever you call that function from.

Comment: I was Trying to call it within a query in a SQL Editor. Is there something I need to do to make that possible?

Comment: Post the query, for one. You can only reference a table function in the `FROM` clause, I suspect you're doing something else.